# Events in dbpedia.org without start and end Date

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, dbpedia

I'm trying to fetch every events in **dbpedia.org** along with their respective **startDate** and **endDate** ( startDate & endDate are attributes defined in http://schema.org/Event )

Here is the sparql request:

```
PREFIX db-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT * 
WHERE {
    ?r  a db-owl:Event .
    OPTIONAL{ ?r db-owl:startDate ?c }
} LIMIT 2000
```

( I'm using [Virtuoso Sparql Query editor](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/) to test it on the http://dbpedia.org/sparql endpoint )

Test by yourself and you see that only a *veeeerryyy* small subset of those events have a specified startDate.

For exemple, if i specialize my query a bit more, like this:

```
PREFIX db-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT * 
WHERE {
    ?r  a db-owl:MilitaryConflict .
    OPTIONAL{ ?r db-owl:startDate ?c }
} LIMIT 2000
```

You can see that startDate is specified in NO militaryConflict .

How can this be possible ?

***I'm i missing something or is it just that the english version of dbpedia is missing some crucial informations like event's startDate ?***

**Note:** If i run the same queries on the french dbpedia endpoint (http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql) , i get totally different results, i.e: a bunch of MilitaryConflict are filled with their corresponding startDate

Comment: It's important to remember that DBpedia data is extracted from Wikipedia data; that different language Wikipedia pages often contain different details; that different language DBpedia extractors may not match up. I encourage you to [get involved in the DBpedia project](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/get-involved), and in [WIkipedia editing](https://www.wikipedia.org/), [especially Infoboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Infobox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, lots (none) of these have **dbo:startDate** properties, but lots of them have **dbo:date** properties, and even more have **dbp:date** properties.  (The ontology values tend to be much cleaner than the raw values, but both can be useful.)  E.g., have a look at the results of:

```sql
SELECT * {
    ?r  a dbo:MilitaryConflict .
    OPTIONAL{ ?r dbo:startDate ?startDate }
    OPTIONAL{ ?r dbo:date ?oDate }
    OPTIONAL{ ?r dbp:date ?pDate }
} LIMIT 2000
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fr%20%20a%20dbo%3AMilitaryConflict%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fr%20dbo%3AstartDate%20%3FstartDate%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fr%20dbo%3Adate%20%3FoDate%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fr%20dbp%3Adate%20%3FpDate%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20LIMIT%202000&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Figuring out what data is and isn't available in DBpedia is something of a trial and error process.  I found the **dbo:date** properties by browsing some of those instances, e.g., [2015 Douma market massacre](http://dbpedia.org/page/2015_Douma_market_massacre) has a value for that property.

> Note: If i run the same queries on the french dbpedia endpoint (http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql) , i get totally different results, i.e: a bunch of MilitaryConflict are filled with their corresponding startDate

This does make the question a bit more interesting, but I'd guess that it comes down to different infoboxes being used on the French DBpedia that helps to get more that information into the system.

Comment: Thanks a lot !

I know that dpo prefix is: http://dbpedia.org/ontology/, 
but what is the full URI for dbp ?

One last thing: How can you use dbp:date results ? They are really ... raw

Comment: @Clement On the public endpoint, there's a link up at the top right, [Namespace Prefixes](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl) that show the predefined prefixes for the endpoint, including `dbp http://dbpedia.org/property/`.  You can also just browse the data.  E.g., when you're looking at http://dbpedia.org/page/2015_Douma_market_massacre and see "dbp:date 2015-08-16 (xsd:date)", the "dbp:date" is link with target `http://dbpedia.org/property/date`.